# Jackson library: Update JsonGenerator

Tags: java, jackson

I have below lines of code:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(writer);
jGenerator.writeStartObject();
jGenerator.writeNumberField("ID", 1); //#1
.
.
//adding more fields, arrays etc... to jGenerator
.
.
jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.close();
```

Now I want to update #1 line with final ID value after processing. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am creating JSON output and have to write "ID" field at the beginning to follow response-format. Since I have written it at the beginning, after complete processing I need to update this specific "ID" field.

Comment: Do you mean within the JSON? Update it to what?

Comment: Update it to new value, from "ID"=1 to "ID"=5.

Comment: Why don't you just write the `ID=5` at the end, when you know its actual final value? Why do you need to write it first?

Comment: "ID" field needs to be written at the start to follow response-format. "ID" is dynamic and value will be dependent upon processing. Its not hard-coded.

Comment: Right, so explain this "response-format". There is no order to key-value pairs within a JSON object.